# mysql select ids from one table which are not found in another table under certain conditions

Tags: mysql, join, exists

Using the following two (simplified) table structures I'd like to find all **DISTINCT** `session_id` values that appear in `TABLE1` where `flag = yes` that **DO NOT** appear in `TABLE2` where `progress = 11`.

`TABLE1` has no duplicate `session_id` values.

**TABLE1**

```
id_table1 | session_id | flag
------------------------------
1         | abcd       | yes
2         | efgh       | no
3         | ijkl       | yes
4         | mnop       | yes
5         | vwxyz      | yes
```

**TABLE2**

```
id_table2 | session_id | progress
---------------------------------
1         | abcd       | 3
2         | efgh       | 11
3         | ijkl       | 2
4         | ijkl       | 7
5         | mnop       | 11
6         | vwxyz      | 10
7         | vwxyz      | 11
```

The expected results here are:

```
abcd
ijkl
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 

DISTINCT t1.session_id 

FROM
    id_table1 t1 

INNER JOIN 
    id_table2 t2 
ON 
    t1.session_id = t2.session_id 

WHERE
    t1.flag = 'yes'
AND
    t2.progress NOT IN(11)
```

Comment: It works, but is very slow... any ideas on how to speed it up?

Comment: Without knowing what your indexes are and what EXPLAIN outputs, it's hard to suggest anything. Is session_id indexed at all?

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct session_id 
from table1 where session_id not in (select session_id from table2) and flag='yes'
```

Comment: This could also be done by doing an inner join on the session_id field.

Comment: I think you don't watch for progress=11